# ExpertPdf - how to generate pdf with marking text possibility from HTML

Tags: pdf

I'm using ExpertPDF library to generate PDF. I had the same code on two different servers. On one of them PDF was generated as a text (I could mark text in pdf and copy). On the second server PDF was generated as a picture, so I couldn't mark text in PDF file.

What is the differenc? Where should I looking for an error?

Now, after installing windows updates on all servers PDF is generateing as a Picture. I think, that updates had main influence on that change, but I'm not shure.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, with an older version of ExpertPdf that used IE for rendering. The problem is fixed in the last version (v9) that does not rely on IE anymore.