# convert html to pdf with ExpertPdf HtmlToPdf Converter

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf-generation, converters, html-to-pdf

I need to convert html to pdf with base64 and ephtmltopdf.dll. The conversion went well. But I can not select PDF content after conversion saved file as an image. I need to be able to select text after conversion. I have tried to change configuration suggested in other posts but still not able to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 types of PDF. `Raster` pdf, which is essentially an image, and `vector` pdf. You need to create vector pdf. And the software you are using is **html-to-pdf** has [documentation](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/docs/html-to-pdf-library/html/1d649728-0ef8-dbd3-3774-07c2501a7a18.htm) about it

```
pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = true;
```

And you can see an [example](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/html-to-pdf-csharp.aspx). Also, see if you are not falling victim of [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494736/1704458)

Comment: @hajar It is working because my answer helped you or because you found it yourself? If my answer helped you, please up-vote on it and it will indicate that this solves the issue you had. Thank you